# Rearranging a JComboBox in reverse

Tags: java, jcombobox

These questions might have really simple answers but in this code

```
public void setupYears()
{
        ArrayList<String> years_tmp = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int years = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)-90 ; years<=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);years++)
        {
          years_tmp.add("Year"+years+"");
        }


        Y = new JComboBox(years_tmp.toArray());

        Y.setLocation(404,310);
        Y.setSize(250,25);
        Y.setEditable(false );
        firstPanel.add(Y);
}
```

How do I firstly reverse the years so the first year would be the current year and the last year would be 90 years ago instead of vice versa?

Also how would I put the "Year" as the first object in the JComboBox instead of "Yearxxxx"?

"xxxx" being whatever year is displayed in the JComboBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the ordering problem:

```
for(int years = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) ; years>=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)-90;years--)
```

And to put "Year" in the first box, simply add the line

```
years_tmp.add("Year");
```

before your for loop.

Hope this helps.